# Shell script to parse through a file ( csv ) and process line by line

Tags: shell, unix

Hi Need a shell script to parse through the csv file - Line by line and then field by field ]

the file will look like this

```
X1,X2,X3,X4
Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4
```

I need to extract each of these X1,X2....

I wrote a script but it fails if the line exceeds one line..

Comment: The good news: two programs, [awk](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk.html) and [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), exist to do exactly that. The bad news: they're impossible to learn. I'm not putting this as an answer because it really isn't; hopefully someone below will post the correct awk/sed syntax for you to use in your specific problem.

Comment: `sed` may be difficult to learn, but `awk` isn't. Awk's actually fairly easy. Although you don't specifically need either to do this, as it can be done with shell built-ins (see Ignacio's response, below).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

First i set the IFS environment variable to tell `read` that "," is the field separator.

```
export IFS=","
```

Given the file "input" containing the data you provided, I can use the following code:

```
cat test | while read a b c d; do echo "$a:$b:$c:$d"; done
```

To quickly recap what is going on above. `cat test |` reads the file and pipes it to `while`. `while` runs the code between `do` and `done` while `read` returns true. `read` reads a line from standard input and separates it into variables ("a", "b", "c" and "d") according to the value of $IFS. Finally `echo` just displays the variables we read.

Which gives me the following output

```
X1:X2:X3:X4
Y1:Y2:Y3:Y4
```

BTW, the [BASH manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) is always good reading. You'll learn something new every time you read it.

Comment: [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) -- you don't need that cat :-)

Comment: @Chris: I know! Just personal preference, for clarity... :-)

Comment: You should almost always use `-r` with `read`. You should do `while IFS=',' read -r a b c d` and you won't have to save and restore the value of `IFS` in order to have its behavior return to normal. Note that if there are more fields in your data than you have variables that the last variable will contain the excess, too.

Comment: Should it not be `given the file "test"`? After all, you `cat` on test, and not on `input`.

Answer (score 4):

Since eykanal mentioned AWk and and `sed`, I thought I'd show how you could use them.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"}{$1=$1; print}' inputfile
```

or

```
sed 's/,/\n/' inputfile
```

Then a shell script could process their output:

```
awk_or_sed_cmd | while read -r field
do
    do_something "$field"
done
```

Of course, you could do the processing within the AWK script:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) do_something($i)}' inputfile
```

Answer (score -1):

> ls -l
>
> vi filename.sh
>
> #!bin/sh
>
> echo "INPUT PATTERN"
>
> cat > test
>   (input data and save it)
>
> cat test | while read (input);(ex : "$a:$b:$c:$d");
>
> done
>
> echo "pattern shown as "$a:$b:$c:$d"\n"
>
> exit(0;);