# code to identify values in comma separated value file

Tags: shell, unix

i want to parse a csv file in a shell script. I want to input the name of the file at the prompt. like :

```
somescript.sh filename
```

Can it be done?

Also, I will read user input to display a particular a particular data number in the csv. 
For example, say the csv file has 10 values in each line:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

And I want to read the 5th value. how can I do it?
And multiple lines are involved.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash shell scripting - CSV parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560393/bash-shell-scripting-csv-parsing) [Shell script to parse thorough a file (csv) and process line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439536/shell-script-to-parse-through-a-file-csv-and-process-line-by-line)

Comment: Try using my FOSS CSV tool at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F, "NR==$2{print \$$3}" "$1"
```

Usage:

```
./test.sh FILENAME LINE_NUMBER FIELD_NUMBER
```

Comment: how to account for the line no.?

Comment: can you tell me what -F and NR mean?

Comment: this is not working for me. i am typing this at the shell. it does nothing

Comment: @amit: Of course. It's intended to work as `somescript.sh`. To use directly from command line type `awk -F, 'NR==6{print $5}' FILENAME_TO_PARSE`.

Comment: if i use it at the commandline, it works fine. but if i type the above code in a shell script and run it. it displays nothing. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: im typing ./fetchvalue.sh newfile.csv 2 2

Comment: im typing exactly that. ./fetchvalue.sh newfile.csv 2 2

Comment: awk -F, 'NR==$2{print \$$3}' $1
+ awk -F, NR==$2{print \$$3} newfile.csv
 syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                NR==$2{print >>>  \ <<< $$3}
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.

Comment: i am using it exactly like you specified. still the error. the command is working fine. but when i put it inside a script, i cannot get teh results. please help?

Answer (score 2):

If your file is really in such a simple format (just commas, no spaces), then `cut -d, -f5` would do the trick.